# Coger parametros de url en Godot html5

Tags: game

Es posible recoger los parametros pasados por url desde dentro de Godot Engine?

Comment: Por favor traduce

Comment: Perdón, pensé que era el ingles.

Comment: Traduce completo por favor no hay necesidad de dejar en inglés

Comment: Esto hay que hacerlo desde JavaScript, y luego accederlo desde Godot. Busca como interactuar con JavaScript desde Godot (depende de la versión, la solución es diferente, cuando escribiste la pregunta era más difícil).